# appendChild no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un div con una template insertada tal y como yo quiero.

Luego declaro un bucle for, para que haga 3 veces un recorrido, en el cual agrego el mismo div al documento.

Pero no me sale y no entiendo por qué:

```
function getTemplate(data){
    let tmp = document.querySelector('#producto');
    let dvt = document.createElement('div');
        dvt.className = 'product';
        dvt.innerHTML = tmp.innerHTML;


    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
        console.log(i);
        document.body.appendChild(dvt);
    }   
}
```

La template ya la edité para que salga algo visible rápidamente:

```
<template id="producto">
        <h2>HOLA</h2>
        <img class="imagen">
        <p class="espec"></p>
    </template>
```

Comment: Yo lo he probado y me funciona, claro que son objetos sin textos y no aparece nada por pantalla. Además en tu código faltan un par de " ; ".

Comment: Me siento tonto ahora mismo...No había caído en que no tiene nada dentro, solo son etiquetas....Gracias...

Answer (score 0):

prueba poner esto y funcionara, eso claro, no veras nada porque el template esta vacio, pero puedes ver en el inspector que si se creo la estructura

```
let tmp = document.querySelector('#producto').content;
    let dvt = document.createElement('div');
        dvt.className = 'product'

    document.body.appendChild(dvt);
    dvt.appendChild(tmp);
```

Comment: Ya funcionaba antes, @Arnau Castellvi ya me dijo que estaba vacío, y no me di cuenta XD
Pero gracias, igualmente tengo otra pregunta relacionada, asi que voy a editar

Answer (score 0):

Contesto tarde, pero puede servirle a alguien más.

A mi me ocurría lo mismo. Pero observé que funcionaba en el elemento del último bucle.

En esta dirección indican que si se crea sólo un elemento con createElement y se inserta en varias posiciones, no se copia, sino que se mueve de posición:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Para evitar esto, clona el elemento con cloneNode:

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
    console.log(i);
    document.body.appendChild(dvt);;
   dvt = dvt.cloneNode(true);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode